# taking a list of dictionaries as input from a file

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary

I want to take the following list of dictionaries as input from a file  called IP.txt and the store it in a variable called lst:

```
[{"date":"30-Apr-12","price":583.98},{"date":"1-May-12","price":58}]
```

How should i do it?

Comment: Take a look at the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.

Comment: It is straight forward if you use the `json` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import json    
with open("IP.txt") as json_file:
        Ist= json.load(json_file)
        print(Ist)

>>>[{'price': 583.98, 'date': '30-Apr-12'}, {'price': 58, 'date': '1-May-12'}]
```